# LaTeX API for C# to generate LaTeX based pdf

Tags: pdftex, pdf

C# has APIs which can generate pdf from the html content. But, knowing the LaTeX features, I would like to incorporate them too. Say, the person fills a registration form. On clicking the submit button, the details get stored in the Database. So, now If I want to display a page with with details, I would get the content from the database, place it in the proper position, get the html page and generate the pdf. Now, I would to incorporate LaTeX in this. That is, the structure and the location of the textboxes and the text font must be decided by LaTeX. The program html content must be passed to LaTeX and LaTeX should generate the pdf. How do I do that in C#. Definitely, there must be APIs to execute external programs. So I would execute `pdflatex main.tex`. This `main.tex` will contain only the structure no data. My question is, how to combine these too?

Comment: Isn't there a `system()" command in C#, such as in usual C/C++?

Comment: There is no official API, but a LaTeX document source is plain text with markup, so you can generate it by hand or with a template language, then call `pdflatex` from the command line or with a `system` equivalent.